# Issue with Zsh Shell Script and Trap SIGHUP Causing Terminal Freezing

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm encountering an issue with a Zsh shell script involving trapping the `SIGHUP` signal.  I have the following script sourced in my `.zshrc` file:

`testdemo.sh`

```
function testdemo {
    touch xxx.txt
    function tester_demo {
        rm -f xxx.txt
        trap - SIGHUP
    }
    trap tester_demo SIGHUP
}

testdemo
```

Upon initial execution, the script creates a file named `xxx.txt`, sets up a `tester_demo` function to remove the file, and uses the `trap` command to capture the `SIGHUP` signal and execute the `tester_demo` function.

However, after closing and reopening the terminal, it becomes unresponsive. I have a suspicion that the issue might be similar to some kind of looping call.

I kindly request for assistance to understand why this freezing occurs upon subsequent executions of the script and how I can resolve it. Any insights or suggestions to fix this problem would be highly appreciated.

Thanks for help!

Best regards

Comment: `test` is a very important often used shell built-in command. Using it as a function name is a bad idea

Comment: well, the name 'test' is for example , I actually didn't use this name in my code.

Comment: but thank for reminding, I will change it to 'testdemo'

Comment: I cannot reproduce locking behaviour with your example code; but if you have more than one shell executing this in parallel, existence of the file xxx.txt is meaningless for each instance, because it can be removed anytime, if the own handler was executed (HUP received) or not.

Comment: _after closing and reopening the terminal, it becomes unresponsive_ : What exactly do you mean by "reopening the terminal"? If you start a new terminal (xterm? KDE-Terminal?), it has nothing to do with the traps you have set up in an earlier process, unless you have configured zsh to automatically run `testdemo` on start. Please describe in more detail what steps you are doing specifically, and what "terminal"  and what OS you are using.